# How to import Vue components from browser - via CDN

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, cdn

I'm trying to import a Vue.js component ([@chenfengyuan/vue-qrcode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@chenfengyuan/vue-qrcode)) using UNPKG as CDN.

Currently, my setup works like this:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chenfengyuan/vue-qrcode@1.0.1/dist/vue-qrcode.min.js"></script>
<script>Vue.component(VueQrcode.name, VueQrcode);</script>

<script type="module" src="/client.js"></script>
```

In my `client.js` file I have my Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    msg: "Vue js Hello World - Your First Vue.js App"
  }
});
```

The setup that I would like to achieve is something like this:

```
<script type="module" src="/client.js"></script>
```

Then my `client.js` would look something like this:

```
import Vue from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.10/dist/vue.esm.browser.js'

import VueQrcode from 'https://unpkg.com/@chenfengyuan/vue-qrcode@1.0.1/dist/vue-qrcode.min.js'

Vue.component(VueQrcode.name, VueQrcode);
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    msg: "Vue js Hello World - Your First Vue.js App"
  }
});
```

The Vue template (incrustated in HTML) is the following:

```
<div id="app">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
      <qrcode value="https://queue-r.glitch.me" :options="{ width: 200 }"></qrcode>
</div>
```

But sadly, this approach does not work. All I see in the console is that the custom tag is not recognized. With this approach, I want to achieve full separation of my Vue code from the HTML.

Any hints why it's not working as I want? What do you think?

Comment: Could you post the actual Vue markup/HTML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example you posted works fine, here is a working example.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    msg: "Vue js Hello World - Your First Vue.js App"
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@chenfengyuan/vue-qrcode@1.0.1/dist/vue-qrcode.min.js"></script>
<script>Vue.component(VueQrcode.name, VueQrcode);</script>

<div id="app">
      <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
      <qrcode value="https://queue-r.glitch.me" :options="{ width: 200 }"></qrcode>
</div>
```