# How to use any npm package via a cdn

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, cdn

I am working on a vue app using a cdn. I do not have direct access to node.js and npm. Therefore, I am using a cdn for everything I have used so far or created my own components. I am trying to use vue-pdf to embed and render pdfs directly in my application however there is no vue-pdf cdn to use directly in my application. Therefore, is there some universal method to convert these npm packages available for download and convert to a cdn or hosted locally in my public js folder of my site?

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-pdf

Comment: You can't. Vue ecosystem heavily relies on build step, there's a lot of third-party vue libs that can't be used like that. You make your choice of libs much more narrow this way. "Therefore, is there some universal method to convert these npm packages available for download and convert to a cdn or hosted locally in my public js folder of my site?" - yes. Node is supposed to be used at some point.

Comment: In-browser compilation is **really** not recommended. But it is possible. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58666239/979052) shows an example of using an external library through a CDN, and vue-pdf even has a live [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fossfiddler/5k4ptmqg/145/) linked to in their repo. So it's just a case of putting the two together.

Comment: I do have access to node.js but this website is built unfortunately without it and uses ASP.NET Core razor pages and imports these cdn packages. I can use node.js if there is a way to create a large js file I can throw in my JS folder and use this. Is that more appropriate? I also agree npm and the build step is more efficient and I am ultimately going to convert over to that.

Comment: I've put something together [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72090634/979052), but this is really not ideal. You should definitely not be running any Vue app like this

Comment: @Lissy your here link takes me back to this page? Was that by accident? Also did you provide the pdf.js example answer then remove it? If so it works wonderfly but I am not sure why you wouldnt run any vue app like that? I mean from the cdn standpoint or because <canvas> tags are not appropriate in how pdf.js is developed and its interaction with the virtual DOM?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I deleted my answer since although it works, using Vue like this is really not great. I've un-deleted it so you can check it out now if you like.

Comment: _"I am not sure why you wouldnt run any vue app like that?"_ - Basically, Vue apps usually get compiled down into a bundle, which can then be deployed like any other site. But if you use Vue from a CDN, you're doing the compiling, with Babel within the browser. It's fine for demos, but it would be very very slow, insecure and un-optimized for any production environment. Ideally you should build your app first (with something like rollup or webpack).

Comment: @Lissy93 I have been using this cdn version for some time now. Really I only use the pdf.js , vuetify, and vue cdns for my project. However, you noted it is insecure to do this option. What about the cdn would make this insecure? If i were to import these packages directly to my folder wwwroot folders so I import locally then would that remove the security risk you indicate?